# Ordenar por el máximo año

Tags: select, group-by

Deseo ordenar las ultimas ventas con pago de 30 y 60 dias y ordenar por fecha orden

**SELECT almacen_id, MAX(fecha_orden) as fecha, forma_pago
FROM ventas
WHERE forma_pago = '60 días' OR forma_pago = '30 días'
GROUP BY fecha_orden**

Tengo el error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'ventas.almacen_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: con que base de datos estas trabajando?

Answer (score 0):

El group by debe tener siempre las columnas que no están dentro de las funciones como MAX.

De esta manera, creo que tu query debería ser algo como:

```
SELECT almacen_id, MAX(fecha_orden) as fecha, forma_pago 
FROM ventas 
WHERE forma_pago = '60 días' OR forma_pago = '30 días' 
GROUP BY almacen_id, forma_pago
```

Comment: muchas gracias! solamente debo sacar las dos mayores fechas para esos 2 pagos, solo que ahora me muestran todas las fechas

Comment: @ari entonces usar un ordenamiento descendente y un limit para obtener de ese conjunto solo los valores deseados